# Rails URL routing and grouping posts based on topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails I created `post` model and `posts_controller` which has `Name:string, EMail:string, Message:text, topic_id:integer` columns using scaffold.

I also created a `topic` model and `topics_controller` which has `Topic_Name:string` in it.

I provided the relationship among the models as follows:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'topic_id'
end   

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :topic   
end
```

In `routes.db` I created the nested resources as:

```
resources :topics do
    resources :posts
end
```

`topics_controller.rb` code:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_topic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /topics
  # GET /topics.json
  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
  end

  # GET /topics/1
  # GET /topics/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /topics/new
  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
  end

  # GET /topics/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /topics
  # POST /topics.json
  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to @topic, notice: 'Topic was successfully         created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @topic }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /topics/1
  # PATCH/PUT /topics/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.update(topic_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @topic, notice: 'Topic was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @topic }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /topics/1
  # DELETE /topics/1.json
  def destroy
    @topic.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to topics_url, notice: 'Topic was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:Name)
    end
end
```

`posts_controller` code:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:Name, :Email, :Message, :topic_id)
    end
end
```

I need to group posts using the topic. i.e., On clicking `show` on a particular topic it should go to the URL `/topics/<topic_id>/posts` where it should lists all posts related to that topic and I can create/delete posts belongs to that topic.

Can anyone help doing this..
Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question should be more direct, there's a lot of information that aren't related to the problem (the attributes names, for example), and your goal isn't clear enough.

It seems that you just want to setup the routes, right? You already have all posts related to that topic though the association: `topic.posts`. You just need to setup [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) routes for posts:

```
resources :topics do
  resources :posts
end
```

Also, you don't need the `foreign_key` option since you're using the naming conventions. It seems as well that you named some attributes in upper case, they should be `name`, `email` and `message`.

UPDATE:

In the `index` action, since you want posts belonging to one topic, you need to scope the `@posts` instance variable. Since you're using nested resources, you have the parameter `params[:topic_id]`, so just fetch the topic with `@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])`, then scope the association with `@posts = @topic.posts`. You'll need to do the same for every other action. I recommend that you read a little about associations in Rails, you'll probably need to use methods like `@topic.posts.build` and `@topic.posts.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: Can you give tell the code for that, when I click `show` it is showing only the topic name in URL `topics/topic_id`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem in this link: [Nested resources](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources)
Download the source code and find the solution...